# How to write the function of appropriating of objects of class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I need to assign one object to another object by overloading the "=" operator. Wrote code, but it doesn`t work. What could be the problem?

```
CString operator =(const CString& obj) {
        CString temp;
        temp.c = obj.c;
        temp.length = obj.length;
        return temp;
    }
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CString {
private: 
    char* c;
    int length;
public:
    CString() {
        length = 0;
        c = new char[1];
        *c = 0;
    }
    CString(const char* s) { 
        length = strlen(s);
        c = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { c[i] = s[i]; }
        c[length] = '\0';
    }
    CString(int leng, char* payload) { 
        length = leng;
        c = payload;
    }
    ~CString() {
        delete[] c;
    }
    CString operator +(const CString& b) {
        int newlength = length + b.length;
        char* newstr = new char[newlength + 1];
        strcpy(newstr, c);
        strcpy(newstr + length, b.c);
        return CString(newlength, newstr);
    }
    void Show(void) { cout << c << endl; }
    CString operator =(const CString& obj) {
        CString temp;
        temp.c = obj.c;
        temp.length = obj.length;
        return temp;
    }
};

int main() {
    CString a("First, ");
    CString b("Second.");
    a = c;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how you are making your assignement?

Comment: You should return a reference, not a value.

Comment: Is that a method of the CString class? If so, you never change the instance of it, just the temporary object.

Comment: [Cstring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019#operator_eq) already has this operator. What is your objective?

Comment: Edited the message, added the code

Comment: The constructor/copy assignment shall manage the buffer, not just assign the pointer. Otherwise the memory would be deallocated twice (leading to the UB)

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov, complicated. Can you show the code? I don`t really understand this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First comment: as long as you specify the non-trivial destructor, and - even more imortant - the copy assignment, you need to specify the copy constructor as well.

Next, the copy operator shall return the reference to `*this`: this allows you to employ chaining like that: 'a = b = c;'

The copy-assignment may look like that:

```
    CString& operator =(const CString& obj) {
        delete[] c;
        length = obj.length;
        c = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) { c[i] = obj.c[i]; }
        return *this;
    }
```

However, taking my first comment into consideration, you may implement the copying just once:

```
    CString(const CString& obj) {
        length = obj.length;
        c = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) { c[i] = obj.c[i]; }
    }

    CString& operator =(const CString& obj) {
        CString tmp(obj)
        swap(length, tmp.length);
        swap(c, tmp.c);
        return *this;
    }
```

In addition your constructor `CString(int leng, char* payload)` looks suspicious. Do you realize that the c-string has to be allocated with `new` (and will be deleted in destructor)?